# Owlcarousel set display none when it is uploaded on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, owl-carousel

I am trying to set an owl carousel on my landing page . It works fine when i browse it from my working directory . But when i upload it on server (even in local server) it set display:none in css .
I tried changing css and js files but it is not working .

here is my code ---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#main-slider").owlCarousel({
 autoplay:true,
 loop:true, 
 animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    animateIn: 'fadeIn',
    items:1,
    margin:30,
    stagePadding:30,
    smartSpeed:450
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="main-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"> 
      <img src="img/slider.jpg" alt="" />
    </div> 
    <div class="item"> 
      <img src="img/slider2.jpg" alt="" />
    </div> 
    <div class="item"> 
      <img src="img/slider3.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a url we can look at?

Comment: Does it even initialize properly? Does your site run on Wordpress? Try to change `$` into `jQuery` in your `(document).ready`.

Answer (score 2):

If you've used #main-slider id more than once on this page you can get error. Use it once.